# Get followers and following from twitter account in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter

Everybody..

How can I get all followers and following from a user's logged in twitter account in iOS?
Is there any api for that?

please help me..

Comment: This question is vague and broad. The short answer is http://dev.twitter.com/.

Comment: @Audust thanks, But why is someone -ve marking to my question..

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "-ve".

Comment: why the down votes? - obviously new and needs pointing in the right direction, not being down voted - +1 to counteract

Comment: Voting to reopen. This is a pertinent question, particularly in iOS 5 with the introduction of the `TWRequest` class and general twitter integration. Since I can't post an answer at the moment, I would advise you to look at the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Twitter/Reference/TWRequestClassRef/Reference/Reference.html) for this class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is an API for that. see [this](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api).

I recommend using the JSON API as it is very easy to parse with the objective-c framework. Look at the fourth section on the page I linked to, under 'Friends and Followers' and you'll see there are requests you can make to access followers and following.

For example, this is how you get someone's followers:

http://api.twitter.com/1/followers/ids.json?id=myuser

This returns a JSON array of user IDs which you can use in conjunction with other APIs to get their user info.

Hope this helps you getting started

Comment: i tried to call this api but getting the error code 68 for migrate the 1.0 to 1.1. **how can i migrate the api?**

Comment: Change the link to 1.1