# Get followers and following from twitter account in iOS using Twitter+OAuth

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, twitter, twitter-oauth

In my application I am using Twitter+OAuth for Twitter authentication and now I need to display the list of user's followers and following with their name and picture and also need to invite them for my application....How can I do that?

I have tried this APi api.twitter.com/1/followers/ids.json?id=myuser This returns a JSON array of user IDs which I can use in conjunction with other APIs to get their user info. But its limited upto 100 users

and api.twitter.com/1/followers/ids.json?id=myuser it only gives the ids. For other information everytime I need to call the lookup api to get other info.Is there any way so I can get all info in one api call?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://api.twitter.com/1/followers/ids.json?id=myuser
This returns a JSON array of user IDs which I can use in conjunction with other APIs to get their user info. But its limited upto 100 users

Comment: and api.twitter.com/1/followers/ids.json?id=myuser it only gives the ids. For other information everytime I need to call the lookup api to get other info.Is there any way so I can get all info in one api call?

Answer (score 0):

[Get Followers form Twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6834931/get-followers-and-following-from-twitter-account-in-ios)

Hope it help to you

Comment: http://api.twitter.com/1/followers/ids.json?id=myuser this only returns the array of ids and only upto 100 followers...What if followers are more than 100?